# How to display 2 button in horizontal in IE7?

Tags: html, css

How to display 2 button in horizontal in IE7 ?

In chrome is OK , but in IE7 not OK.

```
<div>
    <form method="POST" action="" style=" float: left; display: inline-block; ">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Withdraw">
    </form> &nbsp;
    <form method="POST" action="" style=" float: left; display: inline-block; padding-left: 5px; ">
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Refund" onclick="return confirmSubmit()">
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`inline-block` is not supported in IE7. Set it to `float:left;display:block;` or simply `zoom:1;display:inline;` without `float` at all.

Comment: NOT WORK 

`<div>
    <form method="POST" action="" style=" float: left; display: inline-block; ">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Withdraw">
    </form> &nbsp;
    <form method="POST" action="" style=" float: left; display: inline-block; padding-left: 5px; ">
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Refund" onclick="return confirmSubmit()">
    </form>
</div>`

Comment: You didnt change anything? Said `inline-block` is NOT supported. Check the code you gave. It still contains it. Tip: form style.